# Read variable as an argument on execution

Tags: c++, c

I've written a program which only needs one integer at input (N).
I want to somehow write it so that it takes this value at execution, like so:

```
g++ solve.cpp -o solve
solve 6
```

Where 6 (N) can be any integer.

---

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I've tried using:

```
int main(int N) { ... }
```

and I end up getting the warning:

```
solve.cpp:5:5: warning: ‘int main(int)’ takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
 int main(int N)
```

Which still let's it compile, however now it ends up getting N = 2 no matter what input I use for N.

Any idea how this can be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("not enough numbers or too many\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%d\n", atoi(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

**argc** value is in fact number of your arguments + 1, so if you execute just `solve`, then value of argc will be 1. While passing one number (N) as an argument like: `solve 6`, argc will be 2. That is the explanation for my if condition, because if argc is different than 2, you may return an error.

Comment: Ah this makes a lot more sense.  Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!